# SQL Server: Automatically Data Deletion After Successful Transaction

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, sql-delete, delete-row

In SQL Server, I inserted data into multiple tables through a stored procedure. In the procedure, I used `try-catch` and transaction statements. But after insert, sometimes later data is automatically deleted from the database. What could be the possible reason for this deletion?

Comment: Could be rollbacks elsewhere, could be triggers, could be constraint violations being swallowed, ... hard to give you much help without seeing a full slice of the code.

Comment: how it could be roll back after getting positive response of successful transaction? There is no triggers and this occurs sometimes. Most of the time its doing good. @S.C.

Comment: Based on the explanation it could be anything. Maybe something completely unrelated is deleting it. If a transaction was being held open for an extended time, then rolling back, you would have all kinds of locking and deadlock issues. Is this in any way enlightening: http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html

Comment: @Ahsan02 You can get a successful commit of an inner transaction but the outer transaction it was nested in could still be rolled back. Do you know it's being deleted and not just not committed? Try using the SQL Profiler to start a trace and just leave that running until you observe this issue happen again. That might capture something that will point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

check stored procedure. without delete command, it won't vanish from the SQl Server